# SpriteKit - move Object exact distance in one Frame using Physics / Velocity

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

i am again working on a kind of AirHockey game for a custom made Touchengine.

My problem is the combination of exact position updates and the physics engine.

example: Each frame i get the position of my touch. Lets say in last frame it was (100,100) and now it is (200, 100). Now i want a SKNode with a PhysicsBody, that moves from (100,100) to (200,100) in exactly one frame.

Just setting the velocity to (100, 0) does not work, since it moves somehow differently. SKActions do not apply any Forces. Just setting the position does also not work ...

Any ideas?

edit1: I tried to constraint a physics object to a node that i the just move. Does not work. The constraints seem to only reset the position, without physics.
I also tried to pin the physics to another node, does only apply when moved by physics...

Comment: Trying to implement precise positioning / movement with a physics engine is next to impossible unless you have total control over the physics (meaning: the source code). I would suggest looking into alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, maybe i can learn some different stuff, but atm. i am forced to use SpriteKit. I have some workaround, that works fine for me. I will put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

I know not much of physics engines, but i will believe LearnCocos2D and not search for any further precise solutions, but i got a solution that works fine for me:

I use the different steps of the SpriteKit loop:

**-(void)update**

-first: i use the new touch position to calculate a movement vector between old and new position

-second: i multiply the vector by some factor (in my case 15) to get to nearly the same distance in one frame

-third: set the objects velocity to this vector

**-(void)didSimulatePhysics**

 (the object is now nearly at my wished position)

To ensure that the object really sticks to the touch, set the position of the object exactly to the touch position.

I know, this is not 100% and sometimes there are small overlappings, since the position of the object is not exactly where it was in the physics engine, but hey it works good enough. Maybe the factor 15 can be adjusted dynamic, to ensure a better behaviour, but i do not need it, so i do not use time on it. (Still if someone knows a better solution i would be glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

In Box2D worked pretty well to apply a force in the desired direction and then, once body gets to position, apply a growing damping to the body until speed is 0 so that effect does not feel unnatural. You can start applying the damping once objects is getting close to the destination but it would be quite volatile if you decide to change physics properties of body or the world.

As far as i'm concerned you could do the same in SpriteKit through `velocity` and `linearDamping` properties of `SKPhysicsBody`.

If damping doesn't work you could also apply an opposing force instead.

I don't have any SpriteKit example but I could provide one in Box2d if that would help...

EDITED once again to add a sample of this. Should test how it interacts with another body and tune up some values to get the desired effect.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {


    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);



    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    [sprite setScale:0.5f];
    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
    sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:sprite];
    self.mallet = sprite;

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        self.touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        self.controlling = YES;

    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.controlling = NO;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (self.controlling) {
        CGFloat distance = hypotf(self.mallet.position.x - self.touchLocation.x, self.mallet.position.y - self.touchLocation.y);
        CGFloat damping = sqrt(distance * 100);


        if (damping < 0) {
            damping = 0.0f;
        }

        self.mallet.physicsBody.linearDamping = damping;
        self.mallet.physicsBody.angularDamping = damping;

        CGPoint bodyPos = self.mallet.position;
        CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(self.touchLocation.x - bodyPos.x, self.touchLocation.y - bodyPos.y);
        self.mallet.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(translation.x * 100,
                                                        translation.y * 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it should be some kind of AirHockey game. The Player controls the mallets to hit the puck which then bounces over the gamefield. 
The problem is, that i do not know which force to apply to move an object in a single frame to a wanted position.
The user should not get any delays between finger movement and seen reaction. So i can not just move in somewhat speed in one direction and then start damping.

Comment: From what I've seen in other Air Hockey games there's a little delay in the control of the mallet, not enough to affect gameplay tho.

In Box2d you could use a mouseJoint to simulate a kind of rope between the touch point and the body you were trying to control. Take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348419/how-to-implement-mouse-joint-in-sprite-kit

Anyhow, your answer could be in any of the SKPhysicsJoints. Sorry not to be of more help.

I may try to make an test out of curiosity.